# tinymce angular templates replacement variables - how to get variables to reset and be dynamic on each load?

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I'm using TinyMCE editor component in my Angular 7 app. When i insert a template variable into the editor:

```
<span class="data-variable">${variable_name}</span>
```

It gets replaced fine with a value from my template_replace_values object i initialize tinymce with:

```
let template_replace_values = {variable_name: "hello world!"}
```

Ouput:

```
<span class="data-variable">hello world!</span>
```

However when i save this, it would save the static value and not the template variable as i expected like below:

```
<span class="data-variable">${variable_name}</span>
```

I thought this transformation was built in both ways but i find the documentation unclear, and would hate to craft something myself if it is already built in and i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how that plugin is designed to work.  The replacement is a one time task at the point that it is inserted.  If you wanted different behavior you would have to modify that plugin to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, What is mean by cleanup proc then? The documentation says this:  "A template has more capabilities than a simple snippet, for example, a template can have dynamic content/smart content that gets updated by functions located in the template_replace_values key. These functions will continue to be executed each time a cleanup procedure is performed."